# How to access the properties of an XML string converted to an object

Tags: php, xml, object, xml-parsing

I used a web service that returns the result in `XML` format. The method `simplexml_load_string()` was used to convert it to an object like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result[$webresult]);
```

Below is a sample display using
`print_r($xml)` :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [record] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [txnref] => 6113229211825720 [channel] => mastercard [amount] => 3000.00 [payment_date] => 8/17/2013 9:18:25 PM [payment_status] => successful [field_values] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [field_values] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [field] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [names] => Frank [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [amount] => 3000 [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [currency] => NGN [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [email_address] => chibuzo.henry@gmail.com [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [phone_number] => 08035653468 [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [merch_txnref] => 134 [acct_desc] => False [acct_desc_order] => 0 [hidden] => False [defaultvalue] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [xpath_field] => 0 ) ) ) ) [payment_status_description] => Transaction Successful - Approved ) )
```

However, when I try to access the object `$xml`, this way:

```
$xml->amount;
```

it doesn't return any result. How do I access the properties of the object correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount property is in a record object so try `$xml->record->amount;`

Answer (score 1):

Amount is in Record object so use `$xml->record->amount;`

First you print one web service response one necessary step keep in your mind

use `echo "<pre>";`

then you print your `array`

For eg:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

Then only you see the array format clearly